# Different colors on a line separator in Android

Tags: android

I want to add three colors or more vertically on a line separator in android. It is blue as showing in the following picture but what if I want to divide it into three sections and add different colors in it. I do not want to make three separate `views` for this. Can I do it in android?

```
<View 
      android:background="#00bfff" 
      android:layout_width = "match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="5dp"
/>
```

[image]

Comment: use nine patch drawable

Comment: can use image as background for view too

Comment: @VivekMishra No I do not want to add image.

Comment: @pskink Can you give me the example? (the easy one)

Answer (score 2):

Yes You can do it by Making one drawable file like this. And give Backgroung this drawable to view.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
    android:angle="0"
    android:centerColor="#5F3D5E"
    android:endColor="#8F76B0"
    android:startColor="#35293D"
    android:type="linear" />

<corners android:radius="0dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: What if I want to add four colors?

Comment: I think Three color is limit for the gradient.you can't add four color using this method.

Comment: I want to keep it generic.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [layer-list drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) and use that as your `View` background.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="5dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#00ff00" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="10dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#0000ff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Example output:

[image: layer list example]

Edit:

For vertical lines, you do what @convexHull said, just replace `bottom` with `right`.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:right="50dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#00ff00" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:right="100dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#0000ff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Example output:

[image: vertical lines]

Comment: These color lines are horizontal. What if i need these color lines vertically?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Vertical color lines can be done by changing 'android:bottom' to 'android:right'

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Create 3 view and add one below another

**Solution 2**

Create one .png background with  3 different color and set background for your view

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a gradient colour to achieve that effect. Just go into drawable directory and add a new .xml resource into it. Then nest the following:
Selector
Item
Shape
Gradient.
Within the gradient tag add startcolor, centercolor, end color, and angle tags. Then set it as your background of the view.. I don't know of any better way to do this but will update when I do

Comment: Is this method is limited to color ranges? (2,3 colors)

Comment: Yes it is. Last I checked it was limited to a maximum 3 colours.. and it makes a gradient so they aren't cleanly cut out unlike with multiple views

Answer (score 0):

Heres another way if you want more than 3 colors:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/red"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/green"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

So if you want more colors, just change the weightsum of the linearlayout and add another view.